# Drone ssh plugin not triggered

Tags: drone.io

My `drone.yml` file is straightforward:

```
build:
    image: node
    commands:
        - echo $${BRANCH}
deploy:
    ssh:
        host: my-domain
        user: admin
        port: 22
        commands:
            - touch /home/admin/testdrone
```

But in the output it seems like the [ssh plugin](http://readme.drone.io/plugins/ssh/) is never even pulled:

```
[info] Pulling image plugins/drone-git:latest
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /drone/src/github.com/.../.git/
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/....git
$ git fetch --no-tags --depth=50 origin +refs/pull/782/merge:
From https://github.com/...
* branch            refs/pull/782/merge -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
$ echo drone-deploy
drone-deploy
```

How can I investigate what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that deploy steps are only executed if the hook is *not* a Pull Request. That was what was going wrong with my setup